# Call to a member function hashName() on array Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload multiple images in same input and same row in the database
same way worked with me with the single image upload
but I got errors when I try it with Multiple images

here's my code : 
     Controller

```
$files = $request->file('file');
if(!empty($files)) :
    foreach($files as $file) :
      $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
      Storage::putfile('public/images', $request->file('file'));
      $file->move('images/client/preview', $name);
      $car->file = $name;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('file') ? ' has-error' : '' }} ">
  <input class="form-control" type="file" id="files" name="file[]" value="{{ old('file')}}" multiple />
  <output id="list"></output>
  @if($errors->has('file'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
    <b>Alert!</b> {{ $errors->first('file') }}
  </div>
  @endif
</div>
```

Here's The error : 
[image: I got this error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I miss-read your question initially, don't pass request as the second argument of `Storage::putfile()` instead use the variable from your loop

```
$files = $request->file('file');
if(!empty($files)) :
    foreach($files as $file) :
      $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
      Storage::putfile('public/images', $file);
      $file->move('images/client/preview', $name);
      $car->file = $name;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

The reason for the error was because the second argurment of `Storage::putfile()` was an array.

Comment: yes I just fixed it the same way .
you gave me the reason on your first replay . That was because I pass an array and I guessed that I must put $file instead of it .
thank you

Comment: In the docs though they pass in the file though: `$path = Storage::putFile('avatars', $request->file('avatar'));`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: @ConnorLeech yes, but if you are uploading multiple files the `avatar` field will be an array and it is therefore necessary to loop through the multiple files and call `Storage::putFile()` on each individual file.